# How to look at http headers sent by safari?

Tags: safari, http-headers

I been trying to debug an issue that ONLY happens on safai, I get:

> Bad Request - Invalid Header
>
> http Error 400 The request has an invalid header name

However no matter where I look for in the error console, resources, or timeline I cant look at the headers from said request.

Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [http-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-log) and point the Safari URL to localhost:7777 and it will print out what headers Safari is sending.

If you can not change the URL or just want more debugging power you should install a debugging proxy e.g. WebScarab and configure Safari to use that. You get a nice GUI where you can see all the request data: [WebScarab GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRYrF.png)

Http-log only prints it to command line.